# Firestore querying response is out of sync respect with the Firestore Cloud Panel

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The data I'm getting after querying from the external console is out of sync with the data I'm seeing in the Cloud Firestore Panel. The problem was detected since this morning (9:00 GMT-3)

Below is a screenshot of the querying result where the field "nomPart2" that I obtained from querying is "PANEL" (left) and the data for this field in Firestore Panel is "Escritorio" (Rigth).

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGXYd.jpg)

I experience this issue in queries across different platforms: Android, iOS, and Node. I'm not using any TTL (Time To Live)  policy nor persistent data.